# Why in .NET 3.5 L2SQL works dfferent with nullable strings?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

This is my query from Persons table with nullable varchar Name column:

```
(from p in Persons
where p.Name == null || p.Name.Equals(String.Empty)
select p).Count()
```

In .NET 4.0 it translates into:

```
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = ''
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Persons] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Name] IS NULL) OR ([t0].[Name] = @p0)
```

however in .NET 3.5 into:

```
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = ''
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Persons] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Name] = @p0)
```

It seems that 3.5 ignores some record giving incorrect results.

Comment: These are not output of same query. Is EDG field nullable?

Comment: @Hasan Khan - sorry, it should be Name not EDG, I updated question

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking at the wrong query for your .NET 4.0 example. The field being queried on there has nothing to do with the `Name` field that your LINQ query is looking at.

Also be sure that you're actually using LINQ to SQL in both examples. If you built the two separately, there's a chance that the .NET 4.0 example may be using Entity Framework which may possibly produce different queries in some situations.

Comment: Sorry, I've  changed column name into Name in example. I use L2SQL in both examples.